# Наложение картинок в picturebox

Tags: c++-cli

Требуется в Picture box на основную картинку наложить еще пару, подскажите как это реализовать

```
private: Void noPapeperIMG() {

 //Size image
 NoPapepPB->Size = PrinterImage->Size;
 // Set image
 Image^ noPaper = gcnew Bitmap("PrinterStatusNoPaper.png");
 NoPapepPB->Image = noPaper;
 //Add image
 PrinterImage->Controls->Add(NoPapepPB);
 }
```

Comment: Укажите дополнительно библиотеки-фреймворки, хотя бы, а лучше кусок кода.

Comment: Возможно можно добавить все изображения сразу а потом переключатся между ими ?